# Tensorflow Object Detection API - wrong object detection

Tags: tensorflow, object-detection

In Google-colab I am trying to detect car using **Tensorflow Object-Detection API** with `SSD_mobilenet_v1_pets.config`, it detect `humans` as `car` and `car` as `N/A`. The following are the  `size config` and `image dimensions`:

```
anchor_generator {
  ssd_anchor_generator {
    num_layers: 6
    min_scale: 0.2
    max_scale: 0.95
    aspect_ratios: 1.0
    aspect_ratios: 2.0
    aspect_ratios: 0.5
    aspect_ratios: 3.0
    aspect_ratios: 0.3333
  }
}
image_resizer {
  fixed_shape_resizer {
    height: 300
    width: 300
  }
```

I have 1160 images with various dimensions (ex: 73 x 63, 118 x 62, 62 x 56, 71 x 56, 276 x 183, 259 x 184, 318 x 159, 700 x 420, 647 x 407, 897 x 554)

The output I mentioned above:
[image]

[image]

Please clarify, Is the problem of the wrong detection of car is because of the image dimensions or anything else?

Here is my config file

```
    model {
  ssd {
    num_classes: 1
    box_coder {
      faster_rcnn_box_coder {
        y_scale: 10.0
        x_scale: 10.0
        height_scale: 5.0
        width_scale: 5.0
      }
    }
    matcher {
      argmax_matcher {
        matched_threshold: 0.5
        unmatched_threshold: 0.5
        ignore_thresholds: false
        negatives_lower_than_unmatched: true
        force_match_for_each_row: true
      }
    }
    similarity_calculator {
      iou_similarity {
      }
    }
    anchor_generator {
      ssd_anchor_generator {
        num_layers: 6
        min_scale: 0.2
        max_scale: 0.95
        aspect_ratios: 1.0
        aspect_ratios: 2.0
        aspect_ratios: 0.5
        aspect_ratios: 3.0
        aspect_ratios: 0.3333
      }
    }
    image_resizer {
      fixed_shape_resizer {
        height: 300
        width: 300
      }
    }
    box_predictor {
      convolutional_box_predictor {
        min_depth: 0
        max_depth: 0
        num_layers_before_predictor: 0
        use_dropout: false
        dropout_keep_probability: 0.8
        kernel_size: 1
        box_code_size: 4
        apply_sigmoid_to_scores: false
        conv_hyperparams {
          activation: RELU_6,
          regularizer {
            l2_regularizer {
              weight: 0.00004
            }
          }
          initializer {
            truncated_normal_initializer {
              stddev: 0.03
              mean: 0.0
            }
          }
          batch_norm {
            train: true,
            scale: true,
            center: true,
            decay: 0.9997,
            epsilon: 0.001,
          }
        }
      }
    }
    feature_extractor {
      type: 'ssd_mobilenet_v1'
      min_depth: 16
      depth_multiplier: 1.0
      conv_hyperparams {
        activation: RELU_6,
        regularizer {
          l2_regularizer {
            weight: 0.00004
          }
        }
        initializer {
          truncated_normal_initializer {
            stddev: 0.03
            mean: 0.0
          }
        }
        batch_norm {
          train: true,
          scale: true,
          center: true,
          decay: 0.9997,
          epsilon: 0.001,
        }
      }
    }
    loss {
      classification_loss {
        weighted_sigmoid {
          anchorwise_output: true
        }
      }
      localization_loss {
        weighted_smooth_l1 {
          anchorwise_output: true
        }
      }
      hard_example_miner {
        num_hard_examples: 3000
        iou_threshold: 0.99
        loss_type: CLASSIFICATION
        max_negatives_per_positive: 3
        min_negatives_per_image: 0
      }
      classification_weight: 1.0
      localization_weight: 1.0
    }
    normalize_loss_by_num_matches: true
    post_processing {
      batch_non_max_suppression {
        score_threshold: 1e-8
        iou_threshold: 0.6
        max_detections_per_class: 100
        max_total_detections: 100
      }
      score_converter: SIGMOID
    }
  }
}

train_config: {
  batch_size: 32
  optimizer {
    rms_prop_optimizer: {
      learning_rate: {
        exponential_decay_learning_rate {
          initial_learning_rate: 0.004
          decay_steps: 800720
          decay_factor: 0.95
        }
      }
      momentum_optimizer_value: 0.9
      decay: 0.9
      epsilon: 1.0
    }
  }
  fine_tune_checkpoint: "ssd_mobilenet_v1_coco_11_06_2017/model.ckpt"
  from_detection_checkpoint: true
  data_augmentation_options {
    random_horizontal_flip {
    }
  }
  data_augmentation_options {
    ssd_random_crop {
    }
  }
}

train_input_reader: {
  tf_record_input_reader {
    input_path: "object_detection/data/train.record"
  }
  label_map_path: "object_detection/data/object-detection.pbtxt"
}

eval_config: {
  num_examples: 40
}

eval_input_reader: {
  tf_record_input_reader {
    input_path: "object_detection/data/test.record"
  }
  label_map_path: "training/object-detection.pbtxt"
  shuffle: false
  num_readers: 1
}
```

Here is my pbtxt code

```
  item {
  id: 1
  name: 'car'
}
```

I have another Doubt could you guys pls help me
    I try to detect people who not wearing Helmet. I use the same model mentioned above. 
Here is my pbtxt file

```
   item {
   id: 91
   name: 'withouthelmet'
   }
```

And I got this output
[image]

Please help me...

Comment: It seems that the problem is coming from your label map or the num_classes at the beginning of your config file. Can you please share those ?

Comment: Thank you for your reply . I have added the config file. Please let me know what is the problem.

Comment: the problem is your num_classes parameters. If you only have "human" and "car" that's 2 classes, so you should put 2. If you have more, just increase it.
Please let me know if it works so that I can post this as an answer :)

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I have trained only car.  that's why i kept num_classes as 1.

Comment: Ok then you might have a problem in your label_map pbtxt file, it should look like this for you: item {\n id: 0\n name: "car" \n} where \n is a newline

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I have added the pbtxt file. Please let me know if there is any correction.

Comment: I have kept id as 1 is that problem.

Comment: yes, indeed, it's an error from me, id should be 1

Comment: So label map seems ok. One last thing to check : are ou sure you re-trained properly the model with the new classes or are you still using the old pretrained model ?

Comment: It's working correctly now. Thank you so much... @  Aloïs de La Comble, Janikan, Anand C U.  Sorry for the late reply.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help.. I have one more doubt . How do I train an object other than the 90 classes (MS-COCO dataset) like Gun,helmet

Comment: You just change the label map and create a new tfrecord with images from your own class. https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/research/object_detection/g3doc/using_your_own_dataset.md

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @Janikan pointed out, the issue is with the .pbtxt file. Since you are using the default ssd_mobilenet model, it is trained on MS-COCO dataset which actually has 90 classes and the ID for car is 3. Since it can't find the ID 3 in your label map the output is shown as N/A. The ID 1 in the default label map is person, which is why its showing "car" as the classification for all people.

If you want to display only cars. Replace the pbtxt file and edit the visualisation_tools to filter only the class_Id required.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I will re-do the changes you said and let you know.

Comment: hi...@Anand C U, now I try to detect custom object.. like person not wearing helmet. I give ID 1 for 'withouthelmet' it detected every person as withouthelmet is this because of as you said ID 1 is for person.. Then how to train a custom object? pls help me to solve this problem.

Answer (score 0):

Please post your label-map `object-detection.pbtxt`.

I would guess there is only the car class mentioned on first position!?

Comment: Thank you for your reply.. I have added the pbtxt file.

Comment: Like @Anand C U said: if you want tot detect cars as "car" you have to change the ID to 3